# Settingobject property to a value parameter in brackets vs without brackets

Tags: javascript

In the following function, what is the difference between putting the brackets around `value` in `collection[id][prop] = [value]` vs not using brackets?

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    if(value === ""){
      delete collection[id][prop];
    }else if(prop == "tracks"){
      collection[id][prop].push(value);
    }else{ collection[id][prop]= value;
    }
  } else {
    if(value != ""){
      if(prop == "tracks"){
        collection[id][prop] = [value];
      }else{
        collection[id][prop] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the collection of objects for any particular object (here it will be identified by Id ) have certain properties. One of them is "tracks" which is a type of array. In function
its checking for "tracks" property and if it is "tracks" then function want to make sure that its setting it as array. For setting it as array it needs to be with square brackets. If the property is not "tracks" then function want to set the value as it is in what ever form or type its coming.

In first if condition, function checks if "tracks" property already exists on object if it is exist then it just push the new value to existing array. In else condition then the "tracks" property doesnt exist so it set it as new array.

So answer to your question, If you want to set a value as array you need to have square bracket or any other way array can be declare and set.